# Is custom Django user model with only one field possible?

Tags: python, django, django-authentication, django-users

I need a custom user model in Django with only one field to authenticate. Because the users of my website will not have an email or password. They will be logged in with only one string (like token generated immediately). If the string matches with the another string/token defined by my system, the user should be logged in.

How could it be possible?
Thanks

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/customizing/ - there is even an example on how to write a token based authentication backend

Comment: it only shows one line example about that.. i don't have enough experience so I need a help to understand the logic behind that.. thanks..

Comment: You could look into existing Django projects that have a custom Auth backend - for instance: https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar/ or https://github.com/divio/django-cms  - search for `auth` and `login` etc. but still i think the docs are the most useful resource.